# How to extract numbers in the middle of a text file in R

Tags: r

I have text files of following form and I am interested in the middle section with two columns of numbers. How can I read this text file through R.

```
Correct for Electrical Dark: No (NI25D137)
Strobe/Lamp Enabled: No (NI25D137)
Correct for Detector Non-linearity: No (NI25D137)
Correct for Stray Light: No (NI25D137)
Number of Pixels in Processed Spectrum: 256
Begin Processed Spectral Data
857.97  0.000
864.83  7.252
871.70  7.252
878.56  7.155
885.42  7.131
892.27  7.113
End Processed Spectral Data
```

Comment: Does your data actually have lines between each row, or is that a result of pasting it here?

Comment: no it does not have lines in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read line by line using `readLines`. Then, using some regular expression you can keep the numeric lines. I am also removing the extra spaces at the beginning before transforming the cleaned text to a data.frame using `read.table`.

```
ll <- readLines(con = textConnection("COPY YOUR TEXT HERE"))
read.table(text=gsub("^ +","",grep("\\d+[.]\\d+ +\\d+[.]\\d+",ll,value=TRUE)))

     V1    V2
1 857.97 0.000
2 864.83 7.252
3 871.70 7.252
4 878.56 7.155
5 885.42 7.131
6 892.27 7.113
```

Comment: Is there some way I can I do this by accessing the .txt file directly?

Comment: @PrabeshJoshi yes of course. You just replace the con=... by the file name. `readLines(path_filename)`.